# Orchard CMS 1.x [Document Storage] - Mixing Record Backed & Record Less Properties

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms, asp.net-mvc-5

I am following Bertrand Le Roy's guide to migrate OrchardCMS to Document Storage (1.x branch pre release)

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2013/11/04/the-shift-how-orchard-painlessly-shifted-to-document-storage-and-how-it-ll-affect-you.aspx

Here are some extracts from my sample code in an attempt to mix record backed and recordless properties in a ContentPart.

**Migration**

```
public int Create() {
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("CustomerPartRecord", 
            table => table
                .ContentPartRecord()
                .Column<string>("Name")
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("CustomerPart", builder => builder
            .Attachable());

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Customer", 
            type => type
                .WithPart("CommonPart")
                .WithPart("Title")
                .WithPart("CustomerPart")
                .Creatable());
        return 1;
    }
```

**ContentPartRecord**

```
public class CustomerPartRecord : ContentPartRecord {
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**ContentPart**

```
public class CustomerPart : ContentPart<CustomerPartRecord>
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return Record.Name; } // tried "return Retrieve(x=>x.Name);"
        set { Record.Name = value; } // tried "return Store(x=>x.Name, value);"
    }
    public string Phone
    {
        get { return this.Retrieve(x => x.Phone); } //Recordless property
        set { this.Store(x => x.Phone, value); }
    }
    public string Email
    {
        get { return this.Retrieve(x => x.Email); } //Recordless property
        set { this.Store(x => x.Email, value); }
    }
}
```

Throws the following error when trying to add a new record

```
could not insert: [Customers.Models.CustomerPartRecord#28][SQL: INSERT INTO Teknorix_Customers_CustomerPartRecord (Name, Phone, Email, Id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)] ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = Phone ]
```

This works absolutely fine if i add a phone & email column in the DB. but then it writes the data in 2 places. in the xml it will only insert the phone and email fields. and in the table it will insert the entire record.

I am aware if i use Retrieve() in place of this.Retrieve() then it will store the entire record in both places, etc etc...

But Im interested in having just some fields ONLY in the XML infoset and some fields ONLY in the record table. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your part has a record, you can still target properties at the infoset only, without requiring the existence of a record property. To do this, get the infoset using `this.As<InfosetPart>()`. Then, use of of the extension methods from `InfosetHelper`, such as `infosetPart.Retrieve<string>("Phone")` and `infosetPart.Store<string>("Phone", value)`.

Comment: No shortcut method to do this?

Comment: No. Build one if you need it, it's just extension methods.

Comment: Isnt this the same as this.Retrieve(). I know how to access record less properties. How do i access properties that are only on the Record ?

Comment: No, Retrieve will get the property from the infoset if it finds it, then fall back on the record. This goes only against the infoset. To access a property that is only on the record (but why why why would you want to do that?), just access the record: `Record.Phone`.

Comment: Exactly.. I tried Record.Name as per the example above.. and this.Retrieve() for the recordless properties... Doesnt Work!!

Comment: In the above example, Name is a record backed property(say i need this for sorting/filtering etc) and Phone & Email are recordless(need to be in xml only). I have a feeling the Phone & Email properties in my ContentPartRecord shouldn't be there as nHibernate maps those properties to the db table - and thats where its throwing an error. But if i remove these properties, it doesnt let me use this.Retrieve() or Retrieve() in the ContentPart to get the value of Phone & EMail from the XML.

Comment: Well, of course, if you want a property *not* to be mapped, then it has to not be on the Record, and not be in your migration. And of course, if there is no property on the record, then you can't use this.Retrieve. You *have* to use the infoset directly, as I told you before.

Comment: Ok that explains it.. Thanks.. But dont you feel there should have been a better/simpler way to deal with this? You need fields on the record for filtering and sorting so you cant have a ContentPart as only a XML object without a ContentRecord. But with Orchard moving to document storage the only straight forward way to deal with this is to have your entire record duplicated in the Record table as well the Infoset. The performance is definitely not the best with duplicating data overheads.

Comment: Of course you can have a content part that has no record and is all xml. All site settings parts are now exactly that. We do duplicate record properties into the infoset, but that actually *improves* the performance. What are you basing this assertion about perf on?

Comment: You dint seem to understand my question. I know you can have an entire record in infoset.. Say you have an entity called Customer.. Which has the fields Name|Email|Phone|Address|Status. I want to perform a search and sort on the fields Name & Status. Hence they cannot be in the infoset, right? So is it possible to have just the Name & Status in a db table (content record) and the rest in xml infoset??

Comment: Of course, if you need to query on a property, it needs to be on the record. I already answered several times that yes, you can have some properties in the record, and some only in the infoset. In fact, my answer states it quite plainly. I think we're running in circles.